# Use v.split.length in QGIS to split lines into specified length?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile in QGIS that I'm trying to split into a forced length. Lines need to all be exactly 1 mile long - however, I don't know how to force the v.split.length tool to split them this way. Link to file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPxbIcsNJVCYW5yfSkgSTMvAzG71f-4I/view?usp=sharing

I've used the tool to split lines evenly, and I know the tool has the ability to force lengths from what is written in the help information.
[image: Force segments to be exactly of given length]

Is it just a matter of accessing the script behind the tool?

Comment: If you scroll down in the help information, it gives examples of how to use this tool in coding. So maybe try using the Python Console.

Comment: This 'force segments' option is avaiable in the tool's interface in QGIS 3. It works with your dataset, I checked. Alternatively, as @csk mentioned, in QGIS 2.X you'd have to use Python